# Separating several socket.io connections from same user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm developing simple web application using Node.js, Express and socket.io so that one user will be able to type something and other will be able to view it and I really can't get my head around using socket.io.

Flow is that after login, user will see all his conversations. He will be able to click on "edit" or "view" conversation. It will display conversation and everything he will type will be transmitted using socket.io to server and then to anyone who had clicked "view".

Every conversation has its ID and user can view that conversation by going to "/:id/view" and edit by going to "/:id/edit". Problem is when user opens several conversations for editing, I don't know how to separate them. I have this code:

```
app.get("/:id/edit", function(req, res) {
    res.render('editing');
});
```

Problem is that I can't figure out how to tell, when socket.io connects (in `io.on("connection")`), what conversation id it belongs to. I thought that I will use session to save ID of opened conversation, but problem is when user opens two conversations at the same time - it won't be possible to separate these. Another solution I came up with was to render conversation ID in `res.render` into javascript - something like:

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<script>
  var socket = io();
  socket.emit("conversation_id", "{% ID %}");
  ...
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but I think that rendering client-side javascript isn't nice AND there will be huge security problem - once I will restrict viewing documents only to people it belongs to, user will be able to change document ID (since it is client-side) and connect to other documents.

Is there simple, canonical way of how to do this properly? In short, I want to do some alternative of:

```
app.get("/:id/edit", function(req, res) {
    res.render('editing');
    var socket = socket_from_socketio_that_connects_because_of_this;
    socket.on("type", function (data) {
        objects[req.params.id].text.push(data);
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is there a security problem ? Can't you check a user is allowed to enter the conversation whose id he's giving to you ?

Comment: BTW the way *I* do it is to pass to the page the conversation id, let the page ask for the conversation by its id **and** check the user has the right to enter that conversation.

Comment: Yes, if I use integration of socket.io and passportjs, I will be able to query database and check that user has rights for document he is requesting, so you are right. But still, rendering ID to user so he could send it to me back, it doesn't look like nice solution. Besides, templating engines are made for rendering mostly HTML I think, I wouldn't like to render something into javascript.

Comment: How about parsing the current URL on the client-side, extracting the id, and using it to connect?

Comment: I will probably use rendering into javascript as suggested in second comment, but thanks anyway.

Comment: try middleware. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html